# Создание древовидной структуры данных из объектов ссылающихся друг на друга

Tags: java

Есть набор объектов которые ссылаются друг на друга, например:

```
{firsID: 1, secondId: 3}
{firsID: 2, secondId: 1}
{firsID: 3, secondId: 6}
{firsID: 4, secondId: 8}
{firsID: 5, secondId: 6}
{firsID: 6, secondId: 2}
{firsID: 7, secondId: 8}
```

Результатом должно быть дерево, где от "родителя" (элемента не являющимся потомком к другим элементам) можно получить всех его "потомков".
Каким алгоритмом лучше реализовать такую сортировку?

Comment: О какой сортировке вы говорите? У вас есть набор объектов, ссылающихся друг на друга, что сам по себе уже является древовидной структурой. Вопрос в том, чтобы обойти узлы в определённом порядке?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, нужно обойти узлы в определённом порядке

Comment: В определённом - это в каком?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  в любом, главное чтобы в результате получить всех потомков родителя, не только прямых которые на него ссылаются, но и тех что ссылаются на его потомков

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0